# Magneto 2.3.3 db will work with Magento 2.0.8?

Tags: magento, magento2

I am trying to switch website from localhost to server. The website has been developed on Magento 2.3.3 version. but my server has Magento 2.0.8 version installed. The problem is that I don't know Magento 2.0.8 db would be compatible with Magento 2.0.8 version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They are not compatible and there's no plan to support this. Magento2 will throw an exception if it finds there's a difference between db and code. It will also suggest to run setup:upgrade to update your db to use the current code.